# Sending mail through Python SMTP Server

Tags: python, smtp, smtpd

I am trying to build a small SMTP Server through which I can be able to send some messages. Looking at the smtpd library found that there was something. But I only was able to create a server that reads the email received, but never sent it to the address requested.

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
    print 'Receiving message from:', peer
    print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
    print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
    print 'Message length        :', len(data)
    return

server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)

asyncore.loop()
```

client:

```
import smtplib
import email.utils
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Create the message
msg = MIMEText('This is the body of the message.')
msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', 'recipient@example.com'))
msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Author', 'author@example.com'))
msg['Subject'] = 'Simple test message'

server = smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1', 1025)
server.set_debuglevel(True) # show communication with the server
try:
    server.sendmail('author@example.com', ['myadress@gmail.com'], msg.as_string())
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Why do you want to write your own MTA?

Comment: To be able to customize and have everything stored conveniently

Comment: See my answer below. Many good MTA implementations offer quite a lot of configuration options.

Comment: While I agree that you should not write your own MTA, the class [`smtpd.PureProxy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html#pureproxy-objects).  The [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/smtpd.py#l345) shows how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **really** want to do this
then check out the Twisted examples:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/examples/index.html#auto0

I really don't recommend you write your own MTA (*Mail Transfer Agent*) as this is
a complex task with many edge cases and standards to have to worry about.

Use an existing MTA such as Postfix, Exim, or Sendmail.

Comment: No problems. No sense in re-inventing the wheel or wheel(s).